# Does kafka bootstrap.servers support connection for two different clusters

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to establish connection for two different Kafka clusters with Spring application use `bootstrap.servers` config.

Here is my question -- can I use only one `bootstrap.servers` to find servers for two clusters, or I need to use two different `bootstrap.servers`?

I have doubts about this because in [Kafka docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#bootstrap-servers) told about single cluster only.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is correct. It's only one cluster.

That won't stop you from creating two separate clients for each cluster